# Multithread prange loop throws "double free or corruption (fasttop)" error

Tags: python, c, numpy, openmp, cython

I made a few changes to the original question. Turns out the **malloc** part is actually probably the issue, as suggested in the comments.

I want to run a function in a Cython prange loop as in the code below. This code throws a "**double free or corruption (fasttop)**" error.

When I run the code with the prange flag "num_threads=1" all is fine.
I understand my code is not thread safe probably, but I don't understand why.

```py
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef int my_func(int[:] arr_cy, int c) nogil except -1:

    cdef int i
    cdef int *arr_to_process = <int *>malloc(c * sizeof(int))
    if not arr_to_process:
        with gil:
            raise MemoryError()
    try:
        for i in range(c):
            arr_to_process[i] = 1
    finally:
        free(arr_to_process)
    return 0

def going(a):
    cdef int c 
    for c in prange(100000, nogil=True, num_threads=2):
        my_func(a, c)

def get_going(iterations):
    arr = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.intc)
    cdef int [:] arr_v = arr

    for a in range(iterations):
        print('iter %i' %a)
        going(arr_v)
```

if I run `get_going(iterations)`  with enough iterations, like 30, this always throws an error. I feel I am being very dumb but I don't get it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can accidentally end up avoiding this kind of memory-related fault by changing all kinds of things - they usually depend on both a logic error (which will still remain) and the arbitrary arrangement of things in memory (which may change as you make other changes). This is why this kind of problem requires an [mcve] - it is pointless for us to speculate without it

Comment: Ok thank you @DavidW, I will post a complete example. This however means there is nothing wrong with the code posted above, right? I am rather new to Cython so I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code above. This kind of error is caused by freeing the same memory twice, so the `malloc`/`free` part might be important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @DavidW is ok, but it is not a full answer to the problem. After a bit of fiddling I found what I was looking for: I needed to use pointers for the memoryviews, as explained in the **Pass data from a C function via pointer** section on the [cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). Here is the full working code.

```py
cdef int my_func(int arr_cy[], int c) nogil except -1:

    cdef int i
    cdef int *arr_to_process = <int *>malloc(c * sizeof(int))
    if not arr_to_process:
        with gil:
            raise MemoryError()
    try:
        for i in range(c):
            arr_to_process[i] = 1
    finally:
        free(arr_to_process)
    return 0

def going(a):
    cdef int c
    cdef int [:1] arr_v = a
    for c in prange(100000, nogil=True, num_threads=2):
        my_func(&arr_v[0], c)

def get_going(it):
    arr = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.intc)

    for ii in range(it):
        print('iter %i' %ii)
        going(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally identified one issue that wasn't causing your problem but did need fixing (this is now fixed in the edited code): Cython has no way of knowing that the exception has been raised - in the C API an exception is indicated by returning `NULL`, but your function is `void`. See [the relevant bit of the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values). You have two options: define the function with `except *` to always check for an exception, or define it with an error code:

```
    cdef int my_func(int[:] arr_cy, int c) nogil except 1:
        # ... code goes here
        return 0 # indicate no error

Cython will automatically use this when you raise an exception.
```

---

The actual issue is the line `my_func(a, c)`. The conversion from a Numpy array to a memoryview does need some kind of locking (i.e. the GIL) or there's a race condition with reference counting. This race condition causes it to be freed when it shouldn't, hence the error

The solution is to generate a memoryview of `a` outside the loop:

```
cdef int[:] a_mview = a
# then inside the prange loop
     my_func(a_mview, c).
```

Use of the memoryview is fine within the parallel section but it's just the initial creation that's a problem. I think Cython not flagging this as an error when you compile is a bug, and might be worth [reporting](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues).

Comment: Didn't solve the problem unfortunately. I've updated the question following your suggestions (although I'm not sure I understand why I need to initialize c to a value before passing it to prange?) Also please note I've updated the question with num_threads=2, as it was previously set to =1. Although I do explain in the question that I only get the error with num_threads=2, maybe it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry - I'm being really stupid with `c` - I completely missed that it was the loop variable. You don't need to initialise it. My second point is still valid (but may not be your problem). I'll have another look later

Comment: @ffi23 See my edit. With `num_threads=2` I can reproduce your problem and I'm pretty sure this fixes it

Comment: thank you, but I do generate a memoryview before the prange: `cdef int [:] arr_v = arr`. then I just pass that memoryview object to my_func. And then I think I'm creating a  memoryview of a memoryview here: `cdef int my_func(int[:] arr_cy, int c) nogil except -1:` and that is because I don't know how to else write that line. should I pass a pointer to the array instead? how do I do that?

Comment: But `going` doesn't know it's a Cython memoryview. Therefore it has to create a memoryview of that memoryview. You could also fix the problem by defining `def going(int [:] a):` so that it only accepts memoryviews as arguments

Comment: I replied before you'd finished editing your comment so it doesn't quite make sense but: defining the argument of `going` to be a memoryview is definitely the best solution